# Why is the Depiction of the Last Alliance in Rivendell faded out in Lord of the Rings but in Color in The Hobbit?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit

I noticed this and it troubles me because it was a (somewhat inaccurate) painting of Isildur vs Sauron in the War of the Last Alliance. In *The Hobbit*, when Bilbo is wandering about Rivendell by his lonesome, he comes across it and its colored and everything, but in *Lord of the Rings: Fellowship of the Ring* it is faded to greyish and kinda dull colored.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is intentional because Rivendell (and the elves in general) are waning during LOTR but not so much during The Hobbit. AFAIK this is discussed in the extensive documentary videos that come with the extended editions.

Comment: I agree with @muistooshort: _out of universe_ the different color grading symbolizes a different phase in the history of the elves, while _in universe_ it is due to different lighting conditions, as explained by Jason Baker in his answer.

Comment: @mu is too short The Elves were waning just as much during the Hobbit as Lord of the Rings.  As far as the history of Middle Earth goes, not much time passed between them and nothing significant changed for the Elves.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### It's just the light

Here's a better image of the mural, taken from the *Return of the King* extended edition special features<sup>1</sup>, where you can clearly see it in full colour:

[image]

Consider this still from *Fellowship of the Ring*, when Boromir is looking at the painting:

[image]

It's faint, but there *is* colour there; there's some yellow in the bottom-right corner.

Compare the above image to this one, from *An Unexpected Journey*:

[image]

In particular, consider the right-hand edge of the painting, where the shadows are covering it.

*Both* paintings are clearly in colour, but in *Fellowship of the Ring* we only see it under low light, making it appear more blueish.

---

<sup>1</sup> A gallery of the Rivendell murals was one of the exclusive online content features on the EE DVD. The online content is now defunct, but Magpie, a user on TheOneRing.net forums, [archived the murals on Picasa](https://picasaweb.google.com/a.magpies.nest/LOTRMoviesMiscAssociated); may Eru bless you, Magpie

Comment: I agree, I think it's a matter of both _time_ and _date_: Bilbo's stroll around Rivendell happens on the morning / early afternoon of a summer day, while Boromir's scene is set in winter, apparently in the evening / night. The only real difference is the presence of the One Ring on Sauron's finger, wich was added when the set was rebuilt to shoot _The Hobbit_ (illustrator / designer Alan Lee painted the original image, and years later added the ring to it; source: _The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey_ extras, somewhere in the extended edition).

Comment: Add to that he natural fading of sixty years worth of exposure to sunlight (as noted in M.A. Goulding’s answer below), and the difference will likely be even more pronounced.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the painting was new in *An Unexpected Journey* but years or decades older in *Fellowship of the Ring* and thus much more faded.

Comment: Sixty years is a short time for a picture (be it on wall, or plank, or canvas) to degrade to the point of losing all colour :-), _especially_ if it was made by the elves (who should be experts at making _lasting_ things), and _even more especially_ in Rivendell, where the power of one of the Three is at work.